# Any feature to deal with stop-words like "the" in Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using Thinking Sphinx to do hotel search at the moment. I have one item called "Manhattan Club". When I search with the "The Manhattan Club" I get no results. This is because the default :all option means all words must be matched.

I then use the :any option (any word match will count as a match). However this results a lot of results, with the top hotel having lots of 'THE' in its description.

I think the only way to improve relevance is to remove all the stop-words in the search string. I am wondering if Sphinx (or Ruby) has a feature for removing stopwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no idea how exactly how you would do it in thinking sphinx, but yes, Sphinx does have stopwords

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-stopwords

It goes in your index definition in sphinx.conf file. indexer has tools to help you build a list of common words - to help create an initial stopword file.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-indexer

Answer (score 2):

You can set the stopwords file path in config/sphinx.yml - which is organised like config/database.yml (by environment):

```
development:
  stopwords: "/path/to/stopwords.txt"
```

For what exactly goes in the stopwords file, Barry's answer has the relevant links.

Answer (score 1):

To remove high-frequency words from Sphinx index you need to use stopwords directive in your index definition:

```
source my_source
{
   ...
}

index my_index
{
    source = my_source
    path = /path/to/my/index
    ...
    stopwords = /path/to/stopwords/file
}
```

Where stopwords file is simply a word-per-line list of words you'd like to remove from your Sphinx index. Indexer will ignore those words and do not add them to index.

Another way to improve relevance check if you have morphology option in your index config enabled. You may also want to play with ranker on per-query basis.

References:

Pre-generated stopword files: http://astellar.com/2011/12/stopwords-for-sphinx-search/
Morphology: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology